# jQuery radio button value on first click returns undefined until selection changed

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I could use some help with this code.

I have created a fiddle to show the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/r4hqC/

I am trying to read the value of 2 radio groups and then send their values via a GET request (Ajax).

The code works except on the first radio click where the value of the radio is returned as undefined until the radio is changed.  This happens on both groups.

Here is the code:

```
function jsdatabaseMatch()
{
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".form1").change(function () {window.vala = $('.form1:checked').val(); //Radio group 1
         $(".form2").change(function () {window.valb = $('.form2:checked').val(); //Radio group 2
            });
           });
         });
     alert(window.vala); //Radio 1 contains..
     alert(window.valb); //Radio 2 contains..

     var getr = window.vala + "&pricerange=" + window.valb; //GET request
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
         else
         {
             xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.open("GET","showcase.php?yes="+getr,false); //Prepare GET Request
         xmlhttp.send();
         document.getElementById("pricecompare").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

I have tried replacing the `.change` with `.click` the result is the same.

Thanks in advance.

SOLVED BY tymeJV

- Removed `onclick` triggers from HTML which execute `jsdatabaseMatch`.
- Execute `function jsdatabaseMatch()` in jQuery on radio `.change` event.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".form1").change(function () {window.vala = this.value;}); //Radio group 1
    $(".form1").change(jsdatabaseMatch); //Radio group 1
    $(".form2").change(function () {window.valb = this.value;}); //Radio group 2
    $(".form2").change(jsdatabaseMatch); //Radio group 2
    });

function jsdatabaseMatch()
{
    alert(window.vala);
    alert(window.valb);
    var getr = window.vala + "&pricerange=" + window.valb; //GET request
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","showcase.php?yes="+getr,false); //Prepare GET Request
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("pricecompare").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: why `.form1:checked`? if the element isn't checked, then you'll get undefined because the selector doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your change events when they are done. Also, assigned the value using the `this` selector.

```
$(".form1").change(function() {
    window.vala = this.value; //Radio group
}); // <---You can always add .change() right here to fire the event on DOM ready.

$(".form2").change(function () {
    window.valb = this.value; //Radio group 2
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, amended the code.  It works better, ie. now only the initial click which can be in either group returns undefined.  Still not right though.

Comment: So the first time you click on a radio button it's alerting undefined?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with that relevant HTML?

Comment: Yes no problem, back shortly.

Comment: See the update: http://jsfiddle.net/r4hqC/1/ -- You don't need onClick handlers. I simplified this a ton, check it out, let me know what you think.

Comment: Cant thank you enough - Solved it.  I'll update the post with new code.